# Sending data through post request failing

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm trying to send a data to the database, but it keeps failing on me, for validation

I have tried it with a different model, where it worked just fine, but this one is for some reasons keep writting me errors in the BE but looks fine in postman

This is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const FavoritesSchema = new Schema({
    list: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'list'}
});

module.exports = Favorites = mongoose.model('favorites', FavoritesSchema);
```

this is my route with request

```
router.post('/favorites/add', (req, res) => {
    const newFavorites = req.body;
    console.log(newFavorites);
    const favorites = new Favorites ({
        list: newFavorites.list
    });
    favorites.save();
    res.json({favorites: newFavorites})
});
```

The outcome that I would like to see would be to post the id and see the whole object in the database. Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(newFavorites);` and what error did you get?

Comment: I am asking the same question as @CuongLeNgoc.